# Thunder Hooves Issue

Tags: dnd-4e, barbarian

In the following scenario, does the barbarian get the extra 1[W] damage from rage of thunder hooves?

### Setup:

Powers:

```
Pressing Strike
At-Will Standard Action
Melee Weapon
Target: One Creature
Keywords: Primal, Weapon
Effect: Before the attack, you shift 2 squares. You can move through an
enemy's space during the shift but you can't end there.
Attack: Strength vs. AC
Hit: 1[W] + Str modifier damage, and you push the target 1 square. If you are
raging, the attack deals 1d6 extra damage.

Thunder Hooves Rages
Daily Standard Action
Melee Weapon
Target: One Creature
Keywords: Primal, Rage, Weapon
Attack: Strength vs. AC
Hit: 3[W] + Str modifier damage.
Miss: Half damage.
Effect: You enter the rage of the thunder hooves.
Until the rage ends, you can move through one or two enemies' spaces during
each of your turns.
When you move through an enemy's space, your next attack against that enemy
during the same turn deals 1[W] extra Damage.
```

Key:
_: Empty space
L: Part of large monster
W: Wall
B: Barbarian

Example Layout:

```
   North
[_][_][_][W]
[_][_][B][W]
[_][L][L][_]
[_][L][L][_]
[_][_][_][_]
```

Scenario: The barbarian uses Thunder Hooves rage (granting him rage of
thunder hooves), then uses Pressing Strike and shifts south one square, then
east one square.

Observation: It almost seems like the barbarian should have to move entirely
through the monster (the same way you would calculate flanking) in order to
get this bonus, on the other hand the barbarian would be moving through part
of the monster's occupied space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't seen any indication in the rules which says that a "move through" must be a straight line.

In fact, if "move through" meant a straight line, then you wouldn't even be able to make that move using Pressing Strike, as that power states that you may "move through" an enemies space.

Since you are asking about the thunder hooves, and not pressing strike, I assume that means that you realize the move itself is legal.

Since Thunder hooves uses the same language as pressing strike, that means the bonus damage is legal as well.

Answer (score 1):

I see what your question is by looking at the rules of the powers and what you're going for.  The Thunder Hooves power give you the ability to move through squares, but not shift through them.  Effectively, if you used just Thunder Hooves, you'd take an AO when you moved through, since enemies still get AOs when you move through their threatened area, which you are doing.  Pressing strike, however, allows you to shift instead of moving, allowing you free movement without penalty.

Based on the wording of the rules, this is entirely possible to do.  If you were to rage and attack the enemy, then action point and shift through the enemy, your rage bonus goes off, because you met the conditions necessary for it.  You moved through an enemy's square.  It never says you have to do it with the rage's power.  And the bonus damage is after you move, before your next attack.  Pressing strike says that 'Before your attack...', so that means the movement happens before you roll.  That satisfies everything you need.  Because of this, it looks like Pressing Strike is very good synergy with this rage power.  You attack for 3[W], action point, shift through, then attack again for 2[W] + 1d6.  It's an awesome combo, assuming you hit, and works within what the rules are telling you.

Comment: No, I understand.  I was just pointing out that Rage + Action Point + At Will Power was what I assumed his idea was.

Comment: I c. yeah that's a nice combo.